# Generic publish event class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to develop a generic class to raise an event.

On runtime I don't know what entity is going to be there, that's why I decided to make it generic. The problem is, every single type that can be there inherits from a base class `EntityBase`

- In this class I return (or I would like to :P ) the event with the correct type.

  ```
  public class EntityModifiedEventFactory<TEntity> : IEntityModifiedEventFactory<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
  {
      private readonly IEventAggregator eventAggregator;

      public EntityModifiedEventFactory(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
        {
           ParameterChecker.IsNotNull(eventAggregator, "eventAggregator");

           this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        }

      public EntityModifiedEvent<TEntity> Create()
        {
           return this.eventAggregator.GetEvent<EntityModifiedEvent<TEntity>>();
        }
  }
  ```

  Here I call the constructor and then publish the event (not compiling)

  ```
  private void OnNotifyAgentEntityChanged(object sender, EntityChangedEventArgs entityChangedEventArgs)
  {
      ViewModelIdentifierEventArgs<entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType()> eventArgs = new ViewModelIdentifierEventArgs<entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType() > (entityChangedEventArgs.ViewModelIdentifier, (entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType())entityChangedEventArgs.Entity);

      IEntityModifiedEventFactory<entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType() > entityModifiedEventFactory = new EntityModifiedEventFactory<entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType()> ((entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType())entityChangedEventArgs.Entity, this.eventAggregator);
      EntityModifiedEvent<entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType()> entityModifiedEvent = entityModifiedEventFactory.Create();

      entityModifiedEvent.Publish(eventArgs);
  }
  ```

How should I write the specific type to build my `EntityModifiedEventFactory` ? . I tried this `entityChangedEventArgs.Entity.GetType()` but there's no way I can make it work.

If I leave `TEntity` on `IEntityModifiedEventFactory<TEntity> entityModifiedEventFactory...` is going to be an `EntityBase` and I need it to be a `Animal` or a `Tree` type which like I said inherit from `EntityBase`

This is working but I need to change `Tree` type to be whatever it comes from `EntityChangedEventArgs.Entity` :

```
        ViewModelIdentifierEventArgs<Tree> eventArgs = new ViewModelIdentifierEventArgs<Tree>(entityChangedEventArgs.ViewModelIdentifier, (Tree)entityChangedEventArgs.Entity);

        IEntityModifiedEventFactory<Tree> entityModifiedEventFactory = new EntityModifiedEventFactory<Tree> ((Tree)entityChangedEventArgs.Entity, this.eventAggregator);
        EntityModifiedEvent<Tree> entityModifiedEvent = entityModifiedEventFactory.Create();

        entityModifiedEvent.Publish(eventArgs);
```

Comment: There´s no way the **compiler** can infer the type provided at **runtime**. Could you please provide where you call the `OnNotifyAgentEntityChanged`-method? Could you not simply make `EntityChangedEventArgs ` also generic with the correct entit-ytype?

Comment: @HimBromBeere `OnNotifyAgentEntityChanged` its called by a WCF service and it would be so huge to post it here. `OnNotifyAgentEntityChanged` publish the event to those who are subscribed and it's different if the subscriber is a `Tree` or an `Animal`.  It's not the same to publish this `EntityModifiedEvent<Tree>` and publish this `EntityModifiedEvent<Animal>` even though they inherit from `EntityBase`. To be clear my question would be how can (if it's possible ) I "override" the generic type of the `EntityModifiedEventFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally managed to fix this. So this is the answer in case someone goes through something like I did:

```
    private void OnNotifyAgentEntityChanged(object sender, EntityChangedEventArgs entityChangedEventArgs)
    {
        this.PublishEvent((TEntity)entityChangedEventArgs.Entity);
    }

    private void PublishEvent(TEntity entity)
    {
        object args = this.GetEventArgs(entity);
        object eventObject = this.GetEventObject(entity);

        MethodInfo publishMethod = eventObject.GetType().GetMethod("Publish");
        publishMethod.Invoke(eventObject, new[] { args });
    }

    private object GetEventArgs(TEntity entity)
    {
        Type viewModelIdentifierEventArgsType = typeof(ViewModelIdentifierEventArgs<>).MakeGenericType(entity.GetType());
        object args = Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelIdentifierEventArgsType, Guid.NewGuid(), entity);

        return args;
    }

    private object GetEventObject(TEntity entity)
    {
        MethodInfo getEventMethod = typeof(IEventAggregator).GetMethod("GetEvent");
        Type entityModifiedEventType = typeof(EntityModifiedEvent<>).MakeGenericType(entity.GetType());
        MethodInfo genericGetEventMethod = getEventMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityModifiedEventType);
        object eventObject = genericGetEventMethod.Invoke(this.eventAggregator, null);

        return eventObject;
    }
```

By doing this I can publish any `EntityModifiedEvent<>` regardless of the `TEntity`. I just need to add `KnownType`in my `EntityChangedEventArgs` so it can be des/serialized